# ViewDidUnload and ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation replacements for MonoTouch

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, ios6

Now that `viewDidUnload` and `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` have been deprecated with iOS 6, what should we replace them with in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> viewDidUnload

Both `viewDidUnload` and `viewWillUnload` are not called anymore by iOS6. Xamarin's release notes for [MonoTouch 6](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Introduction_to_iOS_6#ViewWillUnload_and_ViewDidUnload_Deprecated) covers this as well as [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload).

> shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Two new methods (in iOS6, available in MonoTouch) can be overridden to get the same result.
See Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a) for the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` selector for more details.

Note that `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is still called (it's deprecated and discouraged for future use, but still available if you support older version of iOS).

Comment: If i'm targeting version 5.1 why am I still getting these warnings? If the device is running 5.1, will the methods be called?

Comment: Because MonoTouch 6 is *in sync* with iOS6 API and `[Obsolete]` allows the C# compiler to issue warnings (but the compiler does not what you're targeting). iOS 5.1 is unchanged so the `viewDidUnload`, `viewWillUnload` will be called like they were before (i.e. it's iOS, not MonoTouch, that stops calling them).

Comment: Does this mean that there is one set of methods (or checks) being issued in iOS 6 and a completely different set in older versions? I understand that this rotation system is now going by the information in the plist and the SupportedInterfaceOrientations method, but is this method supported, and called, in older versions? I doubt every user of our apps will upgrade to iOS 6 so a clearer image of what I'm expected to do with these obsolete warnings would be welcome. For the moment I'm just ignoring them but I hardly say that is safe either.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen neither I or Xamarin have access to iOS code. OTOH Apple already has to check if you override/implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` (e.g. using `respondToSelector`) so adding a 2nd check, inside iOS, is pretty easy (and cheap) for Apple. More details on deprecation was given in the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/12786161/220643

Answer (score 7):

`ViewDidUnload()` you can just remove. If you have code in there, you'll have to move it into ViewWillDisappear() and the counterpart into `ViewWillAppear()`. Relevant talks from WWDC 2012 are episode 236 (The evolution of view controllers) and 200 (What's new in Cocoa Touch).

`ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation()` is replaced by `SupportedInterfaceOrientations().` See here: http://dhilipsiva.com/2012/07/25/ios-6-ui-interface-orientation-shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-not-working.html